Why does getModelJSON on transformer.js throw an error?
I'm using transformer.js within my Angular app. Locally I dont get any errors but on deployment I get the following error:
dialog-agent.component.ts:39 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at hub.js:581:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:17:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:369:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:7251:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:34)
    at ZoneImpl.run (zone.js:111:43)
    at zone.js:2538:40

This seems to be a known error as mentioned here: Transformer.js model fails to parse JSON in client-side Next.js example. As you can see I added the same fix into my app:
  constructor() {
    this.initializeQnA();
  }

  async initializeQnA() {
    this.qnaPipeline = await pipeline('question-answering');
    env.allowLocalModels = false;
    env.useBrowserCache = false;
  }

Sadly, this is isnt working. You can reproduce it here https://mavilio-92fbb--reproduction-j15rn0d0.web.app/. IMO I think I made a mistake but I just cannot find it.
Do you know how to fix it?
